# What is the inverse image when $f$ is a constant function?

Tags: analysis, functions

If I have a function $f: A\rightarrow B$ , The inverse image of a set $H\subseteq B$ is defined by $f^{-1}(H) = \{x\in A\mid f(x)\in H\}$

I think I have a reasonable understanding on finding inverse images when given something like $f(x) = x^2-1$, but I am having trouble comprehending what happens when $f(x) = c\quad$ for some  $c\in\mathbb{R}$. If $H$ is some set $(a,b), [a,b), [a,b], etc\in\mathbb{R}$. What is $f^{-1}(H)$?

Does the size of the set make a difference say $(-\infty,\infty)$ versus $[-3,2]$?

Does inclusion make a difference say $[-3,2]$ versus $(-3,2]$?

I know the elementary fact that the inverse of a constant function would just be a vertical line of the form $x=n,$ $n\in\mathbb{R}$ Which is not a function thus every constant function has no inverse. But I know the inverse-image which is a set has nothing to do with the inverse which is a function. Any guidance or knowledge would be appreciated. Also I am fairly new to working with functions in this manner so I would appreciate a delicate explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\colon A\to B$ is a constant function, i.e. $f(A) = b \in B$ then

$$f^{-1}(\{b\}) = A.$$

Comment: so if I had $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = 2 $ and I want to find $f^{-1}([1,2])$ it would just be $\mathbb{R}$? So will it always be that case no matter the set you are trying to find a inverse-image for?

Comment: Yes, in fact any subset $V\subset \mathbb{R}$ that contains $2$ will have the same preimage as the entire codomain, i.e. 

$$f^{-1}(\{2\}) = f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: The reason for this is that $[1,2] = [1,2) \cup \{2\} $ and preimages respect unions 

$$f^{-1}([1,2]) = f^{-1}\left([1,2)\cup  \{2\} \right) = f^{-1}([1,2)) \cup f^{-1}(\{2\}) = \varnothing \cup \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}$$

(this is true for arbitrary unions)

Comment: Yes, see my previous comment. There you'll see why that holds.

Comment: Thank you so much Zest. I appreciate your patience and clear explanations!

Comment: Glad i could help!:)

Comment: Sorry one last thing but I am assuming the $f^{-1}([1,2))$ is empty because $2$ is not on the line but why did we get rid of the 1? As in what is the difference between $[1,2]$ and {2}? I thought $[1,2]$ is a range interval for which we are trying to find the x values that give us that range.

so if I wanted to find $f^{-1}((1,2)) =\emptyset$?

Comment: Your observations are correct. Any point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with the property $x\not=2$ has the empty set as its preimage. Therefore $f^1(\{1\}) = \varnothing$ and in fact this is the case for any other subset of your codomain $\mathbb{R}$ that does not contain $2$. The intervall $[1,2)$ does not contain $2$, therefore its preimage is empty.

In *terms of their preimages*, there is no difference between $[1,2]$ and $\{2\}$.